# Convert SDO_Contains in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geometry

I have a longitude and latitude values and need to convert Oracle SDO function to PostGIS. My Oracle query is below:

```
SELECT geoid 
FROM   tract 
WHERE  SDO_Contains(
            'GEOM',SDO_GEOMETRY(
                    2001,4326,SDO_POINT_TYPE (
                            '38.841873', '-77.448135',NULL)
                    NULL,NULL)) = 'TRUE';
```

How can I convert it to PostGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if you want to write the query that does exactly the same job then you can find it below:

```
SELECT geoid FROM  tract WHERE ST_Contains("GEOM",ST_SetSrid(ST_Point(38.841873, -77.448135), 4326));
```

Otherwise, please add more detailed explanation.

Comment: I think that needs to be "GEOM" not 'GEOM' in PostGIS otherwise it's a string not a column